# Can't resolve typescript package when using with other module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to create a simple npm package using typescirpt and bundle it through webpack.
When, I try to use the package in other module. Let's see my package name is **'myLibrary'** and then the module is a react application **'module A'**.

In module A I have installed the `myLibrary` package and then import it in some component like this:

```
import { results } from 'myLibrary';
```

And then try to use the `results.add` or `results.subtract`.

Unfortunately, in the module, it throws error that the `myLibrary` can't found. I am wondering what would be the possible reasons:

1. Bad/missing configurations in the `webpack.config` so it doesn't recognize the typescript files.
2. The `tsconfig.json` is still missing something.

Here is the link that have all the files: `webpack.config.js`, `tsconfig.json` and inside the `src>` directory, there are `index.ts` where I have imported the functions.

The [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shirley-ryqhgp?file=/webpack.config.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a problem with configuration. Everything looks good. Your main problem is that you are not exactly bundling the library with your TypeScript code. Rather, you are bundling the application with Webpack. There is a difference between the two.

When you bundle the application, you should use Webpack. When you build and publish a library, you should use Rollup.js or direct TypeScript compiler. When you bundle the application, typically, it is IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression and is a single file which doesn't depend on anything else. That's what Webpack does.

When you publish library, you should simply compile TypeScript files into JavaScript files without bundling into a single file. For this, you should just your TypeScript compiler provided via `tsc` command. And, when you are using something other than TS code like, SVG, CSS, then you need additional tool like Rollup.js. The reason for using Rollup.js is that its preserves your original file structure and emits easy to read ESM or CJS output that can be readily consumed by the applications of your library.

When you compile your TS code, it will generate two files for each TS file - one JS file and another `.d.ts` file which contains type definitions that your applications eventually consume. These files are usually compiled to `dist`, `build` or some equivalent folder. You then use `npm publish` command to publish your package along with these generated files.

In order to teach your application about the Type Definitions of your library, you will need to configure `package.json` file like:

```json
{
  "name": "myLibrary",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
}
```

Notice the use of `main` and `types` fields in your `package.json`. On the application side, TypeScript reads these two fields (only `types` to be more specific) and figure out the type definitions of your library.

This is a classic and still supported way of doing things. If you have a single module export like `import x from 'myLibrary'`, then you can use this. However, if your library/package exposes multiple modules like:

```js
import x from 'myLibrary';
import { a, b } from 'myLibrary/math.js`;
```

Then, you can consider using newer `exports` field like this:

```json
{
  "name": "myLibrary",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/index.js"
    },
    "./math.js": {
      "types": "./dist/math.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/math.js"
    }
  }
}
```

The `exports` field is vast and support many options. Please read the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v20/packages/#exports) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. So, you suggest that, I shouldn't use webpack here?

Comment: I am still bit confused because. We are actually not publishing the package directly to npm but using our artifacts feed in azure devops where all the packages are published and use as npm package in our applications.

Comment: @ninja, It doesn't matter if you publish the package to NPM or not. As long as you use it as a 3rd party package and use it via `node_modules`, you will need to follow these steps. You are simply changing the registry. And yes, do not use Webpack on a library side (There is a way to support it but it is ugly). Use Webpack for Apps only.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful clarifications. I got the point.